# Curious about 'Exclude' option on product image tap

Tags: product, image

Manage Product - Product Detail - Images Tap

There are

Base Image  /   Small Image  /  Thumbnail  /  Exclude  /   Remove

I found most of my image have checked on 'Exclude'

I tried to uncheck or check but can't find anything different

What do this checkbox? Do I have to check or uncheck?

Curious exactly mean the checking 'Exclude'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if an image has the `Exclude` checkbox checked, it will not appear in the product view page in the media gallery images. (small thumbnails).
But it can still be the base image or small image or thumbnail.

It is very useful when you don't want image duplicates.
So you should check the `Exclude` checkbox for the image you set as base image.

Comment: What if need to do this programmatically? i have a situation where images are used on two places how i can get them with custom code? @Marius♦