# What does the exclude checkbox do on the product image creation page?

Tags: product-images, image-upload

What does the exclude checkbox, which is next to the delete ckeckbox do on the product image creation page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer for this already:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/32518/5913

> if an image has the Exclude checkbox checked, it will not appear in
>   the product view page in the media gallery images. (small thumbnails).
>   But it can still be the base image or small image or thumbnail.
>
> It is very useful when you don't want image duplicates. So you should
>   check the Exclude checkbox for the image you set as base image.